# Pig: Force one mapper per input line/row

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a Pig Streaming job where the number of mappers should equal the number of rows/lines in the input file.  I know that setting

```
set mapred.min.split.size 16 
set mapred.max.split.size 16
set pig.noSplitCombination true
```

will ensure that each block is 16 bytes.  But how do I ensure that each map job has exactly one line as input?  The lines are variable length, so using a constant number for `mapred.min.split.size` and `mapred.max.split.size` is not the best solution.

Here is the code I intend to use:

```
input = load 'hdfs://cluster/tmp/input';
DEFINE CMD `/usr/bin/python script.py`;
OP = stream input through CMD;
dump OP;
```

SOLVED!  Thanks to zsxwing

And, in case anyone else runs into this weird nonsense, know this:

To ensure that Pig creates one mapper for each input file you must set

```
set pig.splitCombination false
```

and *not*

```
set pig.noSplitCombination true
```

Why this is the case, I have no idea!

Comment: It's very strange that using one mapper to handle only one line. Why do you have such strange requirement?

Comment: I'm doing cross-validation for a machine learning job.  Each line is a set of parameters.  I have anywhere between 10 and 500 lines.  What's counter-intuitive is that each line is actually an input into a complicated algorithm, and takes 5-ish  minutes of actual compute time.

Comment: How about splitting your one input files to many files (each file contains only one line) at first? You can write a python UDF to do the splitting job.

Comment: Great, thank you!  I'll write my solution up above.

Answer (score 7):

Following your clue, I browsed the Pig source codes to find out the answer.

Set `pig.noSplitCombination` in the Pig script does't work. In the Pig script, you need to use `pig.splitCombination`. Then Pig will set the `pig.noSplitCombination` in **JobConf** according to the value of `pig.splitCombination`.

If you want to set `pig.noSplitCombination` directly, you need to use the command line. For example,

```
pig -Dpig.noSplitCombination=true -f foo.pig
```

The difference between these two ways is: if you use **set** instruction in the Pig script, it is stored in Pig properties. If you use **-D**, it is stored in Hadoop Configuration.

If you use `set pig.noSplitCombination true`, then **(pig.noSplitCombination, true)** is stored in Pig properties. But when Pig wants to init a **JobConf**,  it fetches the value using `pig.splitCombination` from Pig properties. So your setting has not effect. [Here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.9.0/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/mapReduceLayer/JobControlCompiler.java#689) is the source codes. The correct way is `set pig.splitCombination false` as you mentioned.

If you use `-Dpig.noSplitCombination=true`, **(pig.noSplitCombination, true)** is stored in Hadoop Configuration. Since **JobConf** is copied from **Configuration**, the value of **-D** is directly passed to **JobConf**.

At last, PigInputFormat reads `pig.noSplitCombination` from **JobConf** to decide if using the combination. [Here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.9.0/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/mapReduceLayer/PigInputFormat.java#256) is the source codes.